# Раскрываемый блок <div> по нажатию

Tags: javascript

Есть `<div>` блок с такими параметрами:

```css
.text {
  width: 250px;
  background: grey;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus eum harum, nam nulla numquam obcaecati optio pariatur velit voluptates voluptatum! Amet excepturi ipsam ipsum laudantium minus natus obcaecati porro voluptas.</div>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при первом нажатии на блок, он раскрывался вниз и был виден весь текст, а при повторном нажатии он плавно снова принимал свой первоначальный размер?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function classToggle() {
  this.classList.toggle('active');
}
document.querySelector('.text').addEventListener('click', classToggle);
```

```css
.text {
  width: 250px;
  background: grey;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.25s ease-out;
}

.active {
  max-height: 500px;
  transition: max-height 0.35s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus eum harum, nam nulla numquam obcaecati optio pariatur velit voluptates voluptatum! Amet excepturi ipsam ipsum laudantium minus natus obcaecati porro voluptas.</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное